# Number of Elements in a Subgroup Generated by $\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem. The question is:

Find the number of elements in the cyclic subgroup $A$ of $\mathbb C^*$ generated by $\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt2}$.

The solutions says that the answer is simply 8 because $\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt2}$ = $\cos{\frac{2\pi}{8}}$ + $i\sin{\frac{2\pi}{8}}$ is a generator of $A$, but I don't understand where 8 came from. Is it simply trial and error, or is there some intuitive way of getting to 8? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think they are using the (well-known) trig identities $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
Then the point is $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{8}}$, which has order 8.  (In general, if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ has order $n$; this is a good exercise to think about).

Comment: Consider a regular octagon centered at the origin and rotations by $\frac{2\pi}{8}$

Comment: @freeRmodule, is the $e$ the identity element or Euler's number?

Comment: Euler's number.